# Detecting if a series represents a rational function

Tags: fourier-analysis, recurrences, rational-functions

A lemma by Kronecker states that the series $f(z):= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i z^i$ represents a rational function if and only if for every $m \gg 0$ the determinant of the following matrix is equal to zero:

\begin{bmatrix}
    c_0 & c_1 & \cdots & c_m \\
    c_1 & c_2 & \cdots & c_{m+1}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    c_m & c_{m+1} & \cdots & c_{2m}
  \end{bmatrix}

**Question:** What are alternative ways to detect this property, that is $f(z)$ being a rational function?

*Added later:* I am looking for algebraic/analytic characterisations, as I don't have the precise values of $c_i$ at hand. However, I know that $c_i$ are integers if that is of any help.

Comment: The above property is the same as the coefficients $c_i$ satisfies a linear recursion. Detecting this is done by the above determinant trick though...

Answer (score 5):

Probably not what OP is asking for, but a method I find very successful when the coefficients are integers:

Take $c_0,c_1,c_2,\dotsc$ and plug into [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).
If it match a rational function with a description that match the way you produced $f(z)$ you are done.

Comment: Not a very mathematical but certainly a very feasible and indeed successful method. If this had been a facebook post, I'd have added a large smiley!

Comment: You might also try the [gfun package](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/bruno.salvy/software/the-gfun-package/) in Maple.